# How do I use Perl modules from their distribution directory?

Tags: perl, module

Assume I downloaded `Date::Calc` from http://guest.engelschall.com/~sb/download/.

Now, I have a script, `xxx.pl`, which resides in the same directory as the untar-ed "thing" that I downloaded from the link above
When untar-ed, it creates a "Date-Calc-5.6" folder with tons of stuff.

How do I include `Date::Calc` in `xxx.pl`? (I keep getting "Can't locate Date/Calc.pm in @INC" errors)

Comment: What operating system are you using? What version of Perl?

Comment: It sounds like you've downloaded the module and extracted the tar'd file. However, it doesn't seem like you've actually installed the module. You are going to have to do this step. This particular step depends on your operating system. So we need to know the answer to Manni's comment.

Comment: That step doesn't depend on the OS, and only slightly on the version of Perl. For any perl within the last several years, a `cpan .` installs the distribution in the current working directory, and doesn't care what platform you are on.

Answer (score 7):

You first need to [install the module](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html).

In your `@INC` statement, specify the directory containing your Perl modules. Or use the statement: `use lib "path"` to be able to load modules via additional `use` statements.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the module. In most cases, this is best achieved by ignoring the source code tarball and [using the cpan utility](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lNVHi3TunxsC&lpg=PP1&dq=learning%20perl&pg=PA170#v=onepage&q=&f=false) (on *nix) or the PPM manager (on ActivePerl for Windows).

Comment: http://strawberryperl.com/ is another (*and in my opinion superior*) perl for windows. It includes cpan with all that it needs (*make and a compiler*)

Comment: You can install from the current directory with `cpan .`

Answer (score 1):

Installing is the preferred method, but if you just want to try it without installing you can do this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib '/home/jeremy/Desktop/Date-Calc-5.8/lib';
use Date::Calc;
```

Please switch out my directory with where yours is unzipped. Also please read about [lib](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html).

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to build and install the module. If the module is pure Perl and the build process doesn't create any new code files, you may be able to use a module while it's "still in the box". Assuming that's the case, there's more than one way to do it.

**EDIT:** It doesn't look like `Date::Calc` is pure Perl. You will probably at least have to build it before you can use the module.

1. Set the `$PERL5LIB` environment variable to include the package distribution directory.
2. Invoke `perl` with the `-I` switch

   `perl -I/the/distribution/dir myscript.pl`
3. Put the -I switch on the #! (first) line of the script

   `#!/usr/bin/perl -I/the/distribution/dir`
4. Use  `use lib`  in the script

   `use lib qw(/the/distribution/dir);`

   `use The::Package;`
5. Put the distribution directory into the `@INC` variable

   `push @INC, "/the/distribution/dir";`

   `require The::Package;`

or

```
BEGIN {
    push @INC, "/the/distribution/dir";
}
use The::Package;
```